# Creating an Angular 4 datatable from a springboot Rest API

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot, datatable

Hi Im new to angular and Im having issues populating an angular 4 frontend table with user details with id name and surname as columns. I already have a springboot backend which provides user data using rest.

api.service.ts

```js
get(path: string, args?: any): Observable<any> {
  const options = {
    headers: this.headers,
    withCredentials: true
  };

  if (args) {
    options['params'] = serialize(args);
  }

  return this.http.get(path, options)
    .catch(this.checkError.bind(this));
}

post(path: string, body: any, customHeaders?: HttpHeaders): Observable<any> {
  return this.request(path, body, RequestMethod.Post, customHeaders);
}

put(path: string, body: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.request(path, body, RequestMethod.Put);
}

delete(path: string, body?: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.request(path, body, RequestMethod.Delete);
}
```

I Then call all users from my user.service.ts

```js
getAll() {
  return this.apiService.get(this.config.users_url);
}
```

Ive created a table.component.ts but the way in which i was hoping to do it doesnt work and im not sure why.

table.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {
  UserService,
  AuthService
} from '../../service';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls  : [ './table.scss'],
})

export class TablesComponent implements OnInit {

  columns: any[];
  rows: any[];

  constructor(private router: Router, private userservice: userService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let me = this;
    me.getPageData();

    this.columns = [
      {prop: 'id'        , name: 'ID'          , width: 50  },
      {prop: 'firstName' , name: 'First Name'  , width: 120 },
      {prop: 'lastName'  , name: 'Last Name'   , width: 120 }
    ];
  }

  getPageData() {
    let me = this;
    this.userService.getAll().subscribe((data) => {
      this.rows = data.items;
    });
  }

}
```

This is then used in my table.component.html

```html
<div class="pad-16">

  <ngx-datatable
    style='width:900px;'
    [rows]="rows"
    [columns]="columns"
    [headerHeight]="45"
    [rowHeight]="'auto'"
    [columnMode]="'standard'"
    [scrollbarV]="false"
  >
  </ngx-datatable>
</div>
```

Im pretty sure Im making an obvious mistake here and I apologise if it is something basic but I would really appreciate some feedback.

Comment: What is `data.items`?

Comment: You haven't given any details of how things are not working. What is going on that isn't what is expected?

Comment: Whats now working is the getPageData() function in the table.component.ts class. I was thinking that the userService.getAll would populate the rows in a table for each user. Basically I was looking at a github project (https://github.com/mrin9/Angular-SpringBoot-REST-JWT) and I was trying to replicate the use of getting employees and putting them into a table on my application but Im just getting a lot of errors Although I thought I was going about it the right way.